# invoke the jar file command from Flex

Tags: java, actionscript-3, apache-flex

i am trying to invoke .jar file from AIR app.we can do this By `NativeProcess`. my code is next

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                       creationComplete="init()">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            var process:NativeProcess;
            private function init():void
            {
                if (NativeProcess.isSupported) 
                {
                    Alert.show("suport native process.");
                         setupAndLaunch();
                }
            }
            private function setupAndLaunch():void
            {
                var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
                var file:File = File.userDirectory.resolvePath("xyz.jar");

                nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = file;

                process = new NativeProcess();
                process.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);
                process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA, onOutputData);
                process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_DATA, onErrorData);
                process.addEventListener(NativeProcessExitEvent.EXIT, onExit);
                process.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_IO_ERROR, onIOError);
                process.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_IO_ERROR, onIOError);
            }

            public function onOutputData(event:ProgressEvent):void
            {
                trace("Got: ", process.standardOutput.readUTFBytes(process.standardOutput.bytesAvailable)); 
            }

            public function onErrorData(event:ProgressEvent):void
            {
                trace("ERROR -", process.standardError.readUTFBytes(process.standardError.bytesAvailable)); 
            }

            public function onExit(event:NativeProcessExitEvent):void
            {
                trace("Process exited with ", event.exitCode);
            }

            public function onIOError(event:IOErrorEvent):void
            {
                trace(event.toString());
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

while debugging this ,it throws following Error

```
Error: Error #3219: The NativeProcess could not be started. '%1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Plz help me in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally we can't run JAR file directly so here we run through command prompt.Then find cmd.exe path then just follow up below code it works fine. it works for windows only if want to run MacOS then execute shell script(.sh).

Make sure you need add `<supportedProfiles>extendedDesktop desktop</supportedProfiles>` in application descriptor XML file.

Also ensure that java classpath assigned in environment variable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                       creationComplete="init()">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            private var process:NativeProcess;
            private function init():void
            {
                if (NativeProcess.isSupported) 
                {
                    Alert.show("suport native process.");
                    setupAndLaunch();
                }
            }
            private function setupAndLaunch():void
            {
                var cmdFile:File = new File("c:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe");

                var processArgs:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>;               
                processArgs.push("/c"); //Note here
                processArgs.push("java -jar xyz.jar");              

                var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
                nativeProcessStartupInfo.arguments = processArgs;
                nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = cmdFile;
                nativeProcessStartupInfo.workingDirectory = File.userDirectory;

                process = new NativeProcess();              
                process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA, onOutputData);
                process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_DATA, onErrorData);
                process.addEventListener(NativeProcessExitEvent.EXIT, onExit);
                process.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_IO_ERROR, onIOError);
                process.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_IO_ERROR, onIOError);

                process.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);
            }

            public function onOutputData(event:ProgressEvent):void
            {
                trace("Got: ", process.standardOutput.readUTFBytes(process.standardOutput.bytesAvailable)); 
            }

            public function onErrorData(event:ProgressEvent):void
            {
                trace("ERROR -", process.standardError.readUTFBytes(process.standardError.bytesAvailable)); 
            }

            public function onExit(event:NativeProcessExitEvent):void
            {
                trace("Process exited with ", event.exitCode);
            }

            public function onIOError(event:IOErrorEvent):void
            {
                trace(event.toString());
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Comment: jaganath , Thanks for your reply.it works grate but just for my knowledge i want to know why you use  processArgs.push("/c") as an argument?